# Comparing text files on Emacs

Tags: emacs, diff

I have a couple of questions about comparing text files on Emacs

1. I have been playing with `M-x compare-windows` and I read in the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Comparing-Files.html) that, if I pass it a numeric argument, Emacs ignores whitespaces on the comparison, but how do I  pass a numeric argument to this command? (e.g.. if I type `M-x compare-windows` and then I press `space`, it will try to autocomplete with  a `-`)
2. Are there any other more powerful tools or plugins for Emacs (maybe third-party?) for comparing text files?

   For example, on [WinMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winmerge) for Windows, you can compare two documents side-by-side and the program automatically highlights the differences. On WinMerge I can also simultaneously scroll both windows, and it aligns regions with identical text on both windows for easy comparison. [**See a snapshot** here](http://winmerge.org/about/screenshots/screenshot.png).

   Is there anything like this for Emacs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass a numeric argument to a command, enter the argument first. For example, <kbd>Escape</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> moves 3 characters left. So type `ESC 3 ESC x compare-windows RET` or `M-3 M-x compare-windows RET`.

The most frequently used commands to compare two files are those of [ediff](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ediff.html). You can invoke them from the “Tools > Compare (Ediff)” menu. There is a command called `ediff-windows-linewise`, though usually you would compare two buffers (`ediff-buffers`) or two files (`ediff-files`) or two revisions under a version control system (`ediff-revision`). Press `n` and `p` to navigate between diff regions; press `?` to see more available commands.